# HTML5 Embedded Fonts render differently across browsers?

Tags: html, font-face, embedded-fonts

I want to make this page look the same across all browsers.  Specifically, I want the wrapping point of the text to be exactly the same on all browsers so I can create a PDF version with 100% accuracy.  Check this out in FF vs. Chrome, for example.

http://santaspencil.com/desktop/embedded-test/embedded-fonts-test.php

Questions:
- Can it be done?
- Are there alternatives that don't require the user to download a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider embedding the font file into your CSS. But as usual stone-age IE can not do this as you will need to include an EOT font file on your server.

http://base64fonts.com will convert your font files to base64 and then produce a css code for you to copy and paste in your html. this will help with insuring your font loads across browsers (except IE).

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

> ... I want the wrapping point of the text to be exactly the same on all browsers ...

Bang head here (sign on brick wall). Web technology doesn't even try to do this. If you figure out a way to provide your own font -such as embedded webfonts- you can SORTA make it work. But if 100% is your goal, you might as well give up sleeping.

One of the neat things about browsers is their "liquid layout" capabitity, automatically rendering a page differently on a tablet than on a desktop to fill the different screen sizes for example. One of the prices you pay for this infinite rerenderability though is inability to specify the appearance *exactly*. Besides, edge cases will always arise and bite. For example if the available line is 0-73 units and the text you want to put in it is 74 units long, does it "fit" or not??? (i.e. does zero count? and is using up the very last unit a "fit" or an indication of the need to "wrap"?)

The only way to have browsers render your *exact* appearance is to give them what appears to them to be an image. Displaying the text on your screen, taking a screenshot of it, and making that screenshot into a *.GIF is one way.

A PDF file works too, as it appears to a browser to be a "funny" image with its own rendering engine. Most rendering engines are probably the same (i.e. the ones from Adobe) even if the browsers aren't the same, so it's much more likely to work. Providing PDF documents on the web works pretty well and is pretty widely supported. If a URL looks like http://yoursys.yourdomain/yourpath/yourfile.pdf most browsers will fetch it and start their PDF rendering tool and display it directly  ...usually INside the browser window so the user isn't even aware of a different application having been used.

As to the last part of your question, it's the wrong question. It should be "solutions that don't require a plugin THE USER DOESN'T ALREADY HAVE". The advantage of a PDF plugin is the vast majority of users *already* have it. Not all plugins are evil/inconvenient  ...just the less common ones (or the Flash plugin if your target is iPhones where users aren't even allowed to download it:-).

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably way too late, but I did not know this until today.  There is something called a non-breaking space, represented by `&nbsp;` in HTML, you can use to prevent unwanted line breaks or other such thing.  Wikipedia has a pretty good writeup on it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space